# Configure alsa pcm.dmix.rate for a perticular card?

Tags: alsa

folks.
I have an external USB sound card witch may, or may not present in the system depending on my actual location. Previously I used this card as default, so configuration like the following worked just fine:

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.pcm.dmix.rate 176400
defaults.pcm.dmix.format S32_LE
defaults.timer.card 1
```

But since it is possible not to have this card at all, defining it as default is not working anymore, while I still need to redefine `pcm.dmix.rate` and `pcm.dmix.format` for that particular card living system defaults (whatever they are) for builtin card 0.

I did a brief search, but found only examples on defining virtual pcms witch is not what I'm looking for.

aplay -l output:

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Pro [DX3 Pro], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio] <- optional card of interest
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Then here is my external card configured as fully working dmix "device" with a correct sampling rate and format:

```
pcm.dx3proDM {
    type dmix
    ipc_key_add_uid true
    ipc_key 2048 # mandatory, mast be unique
    ipc_perm 0660
    ipc_gid audio
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1"
        rate 176400
        format "S32_LE"
        channels 2
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 8192 # mandatory parameter
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}
```

The problem is that dx3proDM is not usable by the system (I can't select ii as an an output device in Audacous for instance).

I still need to redefine default to point to it:

```
pcm.!default{
    type plug
    slave.pcm "dx3proDM"
}
```

Makeing it default again - exactly opposite to what I'm trying to do.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Having a sound card which may or may not be present sounds like a desktop situation. Is there any particular reason you cannot use Pulseaudio for this (which is the default on the desktop nowadays, anyway), because Pulseaudio will handle that out of the box? In pure ALSA I'd probably do some scripting and change .asoundrc depending on the cards present, but it's a bit of a pain to do...

Comment: @dirkt The reason for not having PA is.. there is no reason for it. It simply gives me nothing extra that ALSA does not.

Comment: Well, in that case it would give you something extra ... but if you don't want to do it the easy way, you need to do it the hard way: write udev rules that trigger if you remove or plug in the soundcard, write a script to change asoundrc. I don't see a way to do it with a static asoundrc - default needs to point to something known. That will take a few days to make it work properly. Installing Pulseaudio takes a couple of minutes.

Comment: There is some misunderstanding. My default  card is snd-hda-intel (index=0), it always present in the system and needs no any specific configuration (work perfect with no asound.conf). What I need is to configure 'pcm.dmix.rate' and 'pcm.dmix.format' of an optional external card (card 1, index=1), not the default one. This external card is a dedicated DAC + headphone amp that I use only for listening to the music (no system/any other disturbing sounds are allowed) and can easily switch the output to in Audacious just for the listening session.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I still don't understand the problem, but I configure my webcam like this:

```
pcm.webcam {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "front:U0x46d0x809"
    rate 48000
    format "S16_LE"
  }
}
```

Is there any reason why cannot configure your optional external card also like this, using the name you get e.g. with `aplay -L`, and setting whatever parameters you need (on the `plug` as well) this way, and not using `defaults`?

Because if you make your configuration card specific, and manually select the `webcam` plugin when needed as output, there's no reason to use `defaults`.

---

> The problem is that dx3proDM is not usable by the system (I can't select ii as an an output device in Audacous for instance).

It's perfectly usable (try something like `aplay -D dx3proDM some_file.wav`), it's just that some applications don't list the plugins, and don't allow you to enter a device name. Which is a limitation of the application, not of ALSA.

> I still need to redefine default to point to it [...]

And then we are back to (1) either use a `udev` script to make that change, or (2) use Pulseaudio, and have it work out of the box.

Comment: I have updated my question. The reason defining card as a slave like I did for dx3proDM as it is not available from the system.

Comment: Audacious does not see this output, not even alsamixed or aplay -l do.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Asoundrc), in particular "Now you can call this newly created virtual device by: `aplay -D rate_convert test.wav`". So it *should* work, and it's difficult to do remote debugging from here. For starters, `aplay -I` won't work, unless that's a typo for `-D`. `alsamixer` definitely won't see it, because those are not mixer settings. And I tried to explain why some applications (I assume Audacious is among those) don't see it. You still have the two options given at the end of the answer.

Comment: In particular, `aplay -l` (small ell) only lists **hardware devices**, not plugins. Applications relying on that to somehow list all possible devices is exactly why applications like Audacious don't work.

Comment: I can make no use of aplay, so there is no difference if it is able to output sound to that pcm. I'm still wondering why it is not possible to configure pcm.dmix of a particular card without making it default like `card 1.pcm.dmix.rate 176400` instead of `defaults.pcm.card 1; defaults.pcm.dmix.rate 176400` and then use it from any application.

Comment: The point is not to use `aplay` or not. The point is that applications need to use the ALSA API to select "virtual" devices (plugins) as well. If they don't do that, because the application programmer never thought about ALSA plugins, and assumed hardware devices are enough, then it doesn't work (like for Audacious). The reason "defaults" works is that it is setting, well, default values for all plugins. "card 1.pcm.dmix..." doesn't make sense, because that's now how ALSA works. You have the wrong model in your head.

Comment: I understand your point of view. Can you give me some example of players except aplay (which is alsa-specific) that support alsa plugins so I can point them out for Audacious developers. I tested mplayer as well, but it seems supports only hw outputs.

Comment: Basically every player that let's you **enter** a device name, instead of presenting you with a list. `mplayer -ao alsa:noblock:device=dx3proDM` will probably work (but I didn't try). If Audacious would let you enter a name, that would be enough. (And I don't expect they'll implement that for you...).

Comment: `-ao alsa:noblock:device=dx3pro` did a trick, actually giving me `AO: [alsa] 176400Hz 2ch s32le (4 bytes per sample)`. The only problem was to feed dmix from plug plugin as dmix itself does not like any rate and format but specified in it, while plug make all obligatory conversions as stated in documentation. The only way to go is to ask alsa-plugins developers to add support of ALSA native plugins, I believe. Or maybe some loopback or dummy ALSA cards, I don't know? Not an ALSA pro.

Comment: "The only way to go" you still have the option to just install Pulseaudio, and make everything work out of the box. Your choice.

Comment: Well.. this happen time to time. The "way to go" emerged just absolutely accidentally while I was searching through the Net for some other ALSA-related thing. The problem wasn't with Audacious, but with ALSA itself. `defaults.namehint.showall on` make my DAC appear in Audacious output list and became perfectly usable.

Comment: Nice. You can also make an answer to this question, and accept it, so anyone looking for this in the future can find it.

Comment: I'm still making experiments with card configuration. I'm going to figure out how dmix affects sound quality and if it reasonable to use direct output to 'hw' device and sacrifice convenience in favor of quality, or dmix is good to go. As soon as I get some definitive results, I will post the complete recipe, this may help other folks having card with special requirement.

Comment: Well, `dmix` doesn't do any conversion, so it won't affect sound quality. It only allows multiple applications to use the same output. The `plug` does the conversions.

Comment: So, you state that plug - > hw is equal in quality to plug -> dmix -> hw if 'plug' and 'hw' sections are the same? P.S. I have `rate_converter "speexrate_best";` in my plug section.